# opencv install - which python wrong symlink + NO library in CMake

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, homebrew

I'm currently trying to install opencv3 on my macbookpro macOS Sierra 10.12.5 and I'm facing some issue I don't understand...

I'm following this tutorial http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/28/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-2-7/

when using homebrew to install python, I have the following console log

```
$ brew install python
Warning: python 2.7.13_1 is already installed
```

doing

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

I have

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

of course I did use

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to reload my profile

--

However, when using `which python` it returns `/Users/hugdubs/Documents/TRYouts/CODE/VENV/compvision/bin/python`
(I'm currently `virtualenv` with name `compvision`)

doing which python2 returns `/Users/hugdubs/Documents/TRYouts/CODE/VENV/compvision/bin/python2`

how is it I can't symlink to `usr/local/bin/python` ?

using `brew unlink python && brew link python` or `brew linkapps python` has no effect

then, and because I don't know if it's related, using the following CMake config:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib \
    -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/ \
    -D PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=ON \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

outputs a config done without python2 libraries:

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /Users/hugdubs/Documents/TRYouts/CODE/VENV/compvision/bin/python (ver 2.7.10)
--     Libraries:                   NO
--     numpy:                       /Users/hugdubs/Documents/TRYouts/CODE/VENV/compvision/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.1)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

doing a simple `$ open /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/` in my terminal opens the finder and I can see that the file is there.
I don't know what to do... Any advice?

Comment: What does `which -a python` say?

Comment: here is what is says:
/Users/hugdubs/Documents/TRYouts/CODE/VENV/compvision/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

Comment: Thanks. What is the output of `brew unlink python && brew link python`?

Comment: Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1... 32 symlinks removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1... 32 symlinks created